# Why do my Google Drive's equations look bad?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

For some reason when I use Google Drive's equation feature, the font that it uses for the equations is....not optimal. It looks really light and just isn't the normal math LaTeX font that I'm used to. On top of that, when I add in symbols (which look nice and properly fonted), as soon as I press space it gets really messed up. Immediately the nice looking symbol is converted to a poorly chosen font. Also if I do something like a square root symbol, the top of the symbol pretends that I have chosen to underline everything. I really can't figure out why this is happening. I'll post a link to show what my equations come out looking like.

http://www.upload-pictures.de/bild.php/38257,unbenanntT9V4L.png

(Please no responses saying "why don't you just use LaTeX to type whatever you are typing?"...as much as I love using LaTeX, sometimes I'd rather save stuff to my Google Drive when I only have to type an equation once or twice per page.)

Comment: I also wish they fix that. Just let us use LaTeX within a text box would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If what you see in the image below does not look bad to you then I suggest because you are not using a suitable style. Entry was "nothing special" (standard entry with default formatting):

[image: WA48719 example]

but the formulae are Title style.

The first inserts Equation only for the `x` (the `= 30` is just standard text).
The second has the text in parentheses is Normal style
The third has a font sized reduced from the default and `x = 25` entered outside the equation.
The fourth has a Normal style `x` (but not for the upper limit of the sum range)